# Time Suggestion overlapping in EWS Managed Api

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS Managed API to get free time slots from Exchange server. But I am facing a certain problem. Suppose I have booked the meeting for 30 minutes from 11.00 to 11.30. But when I am again searching for slots of 45 minutes, then I should not get 10.30 in time suggestions but I am getting that. So please if any one can help me on that.

Comment: how do you 'search for slots of 45 minutes'?

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.